# list selector changes my list entry height size

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView with some xml as the layout file. In this file I have a linearlayout as the root and this linear layout have a 60dp height size.

For the background of this linearlayout I use a list selector - when this particular entry in the list is clicked the background will change to another color (via png - gredient color) while pressed.

The problem is though, when used like this my listView give me different layout height sizes. let say my list have 7 enteries, one of this enteries (randomly chosen as far as I can tell) is a bit taller then the rest.

If I ditch the list selector and use only 1 background png file, I get all of my enteries the same as they should, but I will lose the color change when an entry is pressed.

any idea on this?
here is the code for the list enteries layout.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!-- The selector for this LinearLayout (@drawable/list_selector) -->
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/layoutBG"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"


     android:background="@drawable/list_selector"  


     android:paddingTop="1dp"
     android:paddingBottom="1dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="@color/white"
        android:shadowDx="60"
        android:shadowRadius="60" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rawId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dip" />

      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="@color/white"
        android:shadowDx="60"
        android:shadowRadius="60" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:shadowColor="@color/white"
            android:shadowDx="60"
            android:shadowRadius="60" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="3px"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/info"
                android:textColor="@color/Green2"
                android:textSize="15dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateDisp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="3px"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="3px"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="Day"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shadowColor="@color/white"
        android:shadowDx="60"
        android:shadowRadius="60" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestarted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="@string/timeStarted"
            android:textColor="@color/Green2"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/finish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dip" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="@color/white"
        android:shadowDx="60"
        android:shadowRadius="60" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:shadowColor="@color/white"
            android:shadowDx="60"
            android:shadowRadius="60" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hourMin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/duration"
                android:textColor="@color/Green2"
                android:textSize="15dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shiftDisp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="ShiftDisp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dip" />
         </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

    The list selector xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   


       android:constantSize="true" android:dither="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/li2" android:state_first="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/liner2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/li2" android:state_pressed="false"/>

   </selector>
```

[image: Main list]

[image: entry BG]
[image]

Comment: Double forward slash in xml doesn't create a comment. I've changed it to the right format, for correctness

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Answer myself - I've removed this  android:constantSize="true" from the list selector and now I get the same size like I should.

Answer (score 0):

Your images for the selector might be the problem. Look at them carefully, and see if they are the same height, have same padding, and have the same content area. That should fix your problem.

Comment: But I'm using the same drawable for 2 states (state_first and state_pressed="false"). only the 3rd state_pressed="true" will give me a different drawable and that is not when it happens. It happens in the main list where nothing is pressed and they are using the same drawable.

Comment: Can you post your images and the screenshot of the list as well?